# Very important. ABOUT WOMEN AROUSAL

Tags: salat, women

I am a muslim women. I want an answer that's why i am writing about it. I always have a high hormonal level as im arousal when my period is close. Usually it comes at certain moments. But this time its different. It has been over a week and i am aroused all the time. I dont feel right praying with that feeling but i cant skip my prayers because of it. Some times when i am praying the feeling intensifies. But i dont know if that intensifying is a orgasm or not. But i dont find any najis when i check. So will my prayer be valid or not valid?

I hope to hear a answer. Because i am very furstrated about this.

Thank you in advance for any answer i could get.

Comment: Are you on any medication?

Comment: This questions looks like a better fit on site about sexuality or health than here. Further even their one needs more information. For instance are you married etc.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because on a different SE site about health or sexuality

Answer (score 0):

I am not really knowledgeable but will try to help since your question doesn't seem to be getting answered. Allah is the most merciful, in prayer we may have distracting thoughts blocking us from fully commiting ourselves to prayer. One advice I could give is to truly feel like you are standing in front of Allah swt, imagine that this prayer is your last, fill your thoughts with piety. Fear his punishment, cry out to Him for repentance, with taqwa and imaan in your heart. But you are not sinful for something like this that is not in your control. If there is no reason to do ghusl, then focus on prayer and try pushing away any impure or distracting thoughts. Remember sister Allah swt understands your situation best, He created you, and He is your protector. But please do not think this is a reasoning for you not praying. Also if it is not too dificult, fasting is recommended for Muslims with this issue of arousal if there is no other halal option (marriage). May Allah grant you patience. Also if you are not sure if it is an orgasm while praying, then continue your prayer, if you find later on it was then redoing your prayer is the best option after becoming clean. May Allah give you strength to overcome your difficulties. Medication may help you with your hormones, I would advise you to see a trustable doctor if you can. Salalm

Comment: It is dangerous answering without knowledge Allah the almighty says: "And do not pursue that of which you have no knowledge. Indeed, the hearing, the sight and the heart - about all those [one] will be questioned." [17:36](https://legacy.quran.com/17/36) and on any regular SE site it isn't unusual to leave a question unanswered for days or weeks. Each person thinks that his/her own question  is the most important. But doesn't mean that others agree nor do they need to answer it without having enough insight.